# ssh multiple commands appends question mark to file name

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, bzip2

I have a database transfer script, which uses bzip2 to minimise locking of large databases on a server.

First line is

```
ssh root@server "mysqldump db | bzip2 >/root/db.sql.bz2"
```

This works on many servers, but on a new Ubuntu 14.04 server the file created on the server has a question mark appended:

```
ls -la gt*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2364190 Nov 21 00:25 db.sql.bz2?
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your script have CR+LF line-endings? Make sure to use Unix (LF) line endings.